# К какому из данных оттенков больше относится цвет?

Tags: java, color, rgb

У меня имеется массив цветов (в формате RGB). Я получаю цвет, который должен сравнить по каждой составляющей: красный, зелёный, синий, с данными цветами в массиве. В результате я должен узнать какому цвету с массива больше подобен получаемый цвет. Как это сделать?

Comment: [Формула цветового отличия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Формула_цветового_отличия)

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать решить этот вопрос математическим способом.
Имея допустим три оттенка:`[145,180,70]` , `[160,200,220]` , `[70,45,150]` 
И цвет с числами: `[100,100,100]`
Мы можем провести вычитание по модулю для каждого из чисел и затем сравнить сумму всех этих чисел. Ближайшим оттенком будет цвет, для которого полученный ответ будет наименьшим

Например:
`|145 - 100| + |180 - 100| + |70 - 100| = 155`
`|160 - 100| + |200 - 100| + |220 - 100| = 280`
`|70 - 100| + |45 - 100| + |150 - 100| = 135`
Для третьего оттенка мы получили наименьшее число, следственно, наш цвет расположен ближе всего к третьему оттенку.

Comment: У вас ["манхеттанское" расстояние](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Расстояние_городских_кварталов) используется. Лучше поменять модули на возведение разностей в квадрат, тогда будет по сути [евклидово расстояние](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Евклидова_метрика) (корень можно не извлекать, потому что если квадрат расстояния меньше, то и само расстояние меньше).